A variant of Shapiro inequality
Let $n$ be a natural number and $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ be positive reals. Let $x_0=x_n$ and $x_{n+1}=x_1$.
Is it always true that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{x_{i-1}+x_{i+1}}\ge\dfrac n2$$
I know when $n\le4$, the ineuality is always true:
For $n=1$, the inequality is $\dfrac{x_1}{2x_1}\ge1/2$ which is obviously true.
For $n=2$, the inequality is $\dfrac{x_1}{2x_2}+\dfrac{x_2}{2x_1}\ge1$ which is true as $\dfrac{x_1}{2x_2}+\dfrac{x_2}{2x_1}\ge2\sqrt{\dfrac{x_1}{2x_2}\cdot\dfrac{x_2}{2x_1}}=1$
For $n=3$, the inequality is $\dfrac{x_1}{x_3+x_2}+\dfrac{x_2}{x_1+x_3}+\dfrac{x_3}{x_2+x_1}\ge3/2$ is identical to Shapiro inequality and therefore true.
For $n=4$, the inequality is $\dfrac{x_1}{x_4+x_2}+\dfrac{x_2}{x_1+x_3}+\dfrac{x_3}{x_2+x_4}+\dfrac{x_4}{x_3+x_1}\ge2$. Note that
\begin{align}&\frac{x_1}{x_4+x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_1+x_3}+\frac{x_3}{x_2+x_4}+\frac{x_4}{x_3+x_1}\\
=\,&\frac{x_1+x_3}{x_2+x_4}+\frac{x_2+x_4}{x_1+x_3}\\
\ge\,&2\sqrt{\frac{x_1+x_3}{x_2+x_4}\cdot\frac{x_2+x_4}{x_1+x_3}}\\
=\,&2\end{align}
However, I am unsure whether the inequality is true for all values of $n$.

$\boxed{\text{No}}$, it does not hold for $n\ge5$.
For a counterexample, consider a constant $k>1$, and take $$(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_{n-2},x_{n-1},x_n) = (k^1,k^2,k^3,\ldots,k^{n-2},k^{n-1},k^{n-1}),$$
i.e., $x_i = k^i$ for $i \le n-1$ and $x_n = k^{n-1}$.
This results in
$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{x_i}{x_{i-1}+x_{i+1}} &= \underbrace{ \dfrac{k}{k^{n-1} + k^2} }_{< \ \dfrac1k} + \left( \sum_{i=2}^{n-2} \underbrace{ \dfrac{k^i}{k^{i-1}+k^{i+1}} }_{= \ \dfrac{k}{1+k^2} \ < \ \dfrac1k} \right) + \underbrace{ \dfrac{k^{n-1}}{k^{n-2} + k^{n-1}} }_{< \ 1} + \underbrace{ \dfrac{k^{n-1}}{k^{n-1}+k} }_{< \ 1} \\
&< (n-2) \dfrac1k + 2.
\end{align}$
As $k$ grows, the last expression can be made $< 2+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.
As a result, the greatest lower-bound one can prove for this expression is $2$. For a lower-bound of $\ge2$, see this post.
